# Unity Failed to Re-Package Resources

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Hey guys whenever I try to create an SDK for my game I get this error and I don't know why. I'm really hoping this doesn't mean I have to abandon work on my game after almost a year of working on it.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
C:\Users\jimmy_000\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:\Users\jimmy_000\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.google.firebase.unity:com.google.android.gms.measurement:com.google.android.gms.measurement.impl:com.google.firebase.measurement.impl.license:com.google.firebase.measurement.license:com.google.firebase.unity.analytics:com.google.firebase.unity.app:com.google.firebase.auth.api:com.google.firebase.firebase.auth.api.license:com.google.firebase.unity.auth:com.google.firebase:com.google.firebase.firebase.common.license:com.google.firebase.firebase_core:com.google.firebase.iid:com.google.firebase.firebase.iid.license:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms.base.license:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.common.license:com.google.android.gms.safetynet:com.google.android.gms.tasks:com.google.android.gms.tasks.license:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:android.support.v4:com.google.ads.mediation.unity:com.unity3d.ads:com.unity3d.ads -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-analytics-11.4.2\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-analytics-impl-11.4.2\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-auth-11.4.2\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-common-11.4.2\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-iid-11.4.2\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-11.0.2\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-11.0.2\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-11.0.2\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-11.4.2\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-11.0.2\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-11.4.2\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-safetynet-11.0.2\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-11.4.2\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-compat-25.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-core-ui-25.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-core-utils-25.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-fragment-25.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-media-compat-25.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-24.1.1\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-25.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-adapter-2.1.0.0\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-ads\res" -S "C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-ads-sdk-2.1\res"

stderr[
C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-11.0.2\res\values\values.xml:33: error: Attribute "imageAspectRatioAdjust" already defined with incompatible format.
C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-11.4.2\res\values\values.xml:34: Original attribute defined here.
C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-11.0.2\res\values\values.xml:46: error: Attribute "buttonSize" already defined with incompatible format.
C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-11.4.2\res\values\values.xml:47: Original attribute defined here.
C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-11.0.2\res\values\values.xml:54: error: Attribute "colorScheme" already defined with incompatible format.
C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-11.4.2\res\values\values.xml:55: Original attribute defined here.
]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)

Files:
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
Including resources from package: C:\Users\jimmy_000\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
trying overlaySet Key=common_full_open_on_phone.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_disabled.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=googleg_disabled_color_18.png
trying overlaySet Key=googleg_standard_color_18.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_full_open_on_phone.png
baseFile 0 has flavor hdpi-v4
baseFile 1 has flavor xhdpi-v4
overlayFile 0 has flavor hdpi-v4
overlayFile 1 has flavor xhdpi-v4
found a match (0) for overlay file common_full_open_on_phone.png, for flavor hdpi-v4
found a match (1) for overlay file common_full_open_on_phone.png, for flavor xhdpi-v4
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png
baseFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
baseFile 1 has flavor hdpi-v4
baseFile 2 has flavor xhdpi-v4
baseFile 3 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
overlayFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
overlayFile 1 has flavor hdpi-v4
overlayFile 2 has flavor xhdpi-v4
overlayFile 3 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png, for flavor mdpi-v4
found a match (1) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png, for flavor hdpi-v4
found a match (2) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png, for flavor xhdpi-v4
found a match (3) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png, for flavor xxhdpi-v4
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_disabled.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_disabled.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png
baseFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
baseFile 1 has flavor hdpi-v4
baseFile 2 has flavor xhdpi-v4
baseFile 3 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
overlayFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
overlayFile 1 has flavor hdpi-v4
overlayFile 2 has flavor xhdpi-v4
overlayFile 3 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png, for flavor mdpi-v4
found a match (1) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png, for flavor hdpi-v4
found a match (2) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png, for flavor xhdpi-v4
found a match (3) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png, for flavor xxhdpi-v4
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png
baseFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
baseFile 1 has flavor hdpi-v4
baseFile 2 has flavor xhdpi-v4
baseFile 3 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
overlayFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
overlayFile 1 has flavor hdpi-v4
overlayFile 2 has flavor xhdpi-v4
overlayFile 3 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png, for flavor mdpi-v4
found a match (1) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png, for flavor hdpi-v4
found a match (2) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png, for flavor xhdpi-v4
found a match (3) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png, for flavor xxhdpi-v4
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png
baseFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
baseFile 1 has flavor hdpi-v4
baseFile 2 has flavor xhdpi-v4
baseFile 3 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
overlayFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
overlayFile 1 has flavor hdpi-v4
overlayFile 2 has flavor xhdpi-v4
overlayFile 3 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png, for flavor mdpi-v4
found a match (1) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png, for flavor hdpi-v4
found a match (2) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png, for flavor xhdpi-v4
found a match (3) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png, for flavor xxhdpi-v4
trying overlaySet Key=googleg_disabled_color_18.png
baseFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
baseFile 1 has flavor hdpi-v4
baseFile 2 has flavor xhdpi-v4
baseFile 3 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
overlayFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
overlayFile 1 has flavor hdpi-v4
overlayFile 2 has flavor xhdpi-v4
overlayFile 3 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
found a match (0) for overlay file googleg_disabled_color_18.png, for flavor mdpi-v4
found a match (1) for overlay file googleg_disabled_color_18.png, for flavor hdpi-v4
found a match (2) for overlay file googleg_disabled_color_18.png, for flavor xhdpi-v4
found a match (3) for overlay file googleg_disabled_color_18.png, for flavor xxhdpi-v4
trying overlaySet Key=googleg_standard_color_18.png
baseFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
baseFile 1 has flavor hdpi-v4
baseFile 2 has flavor xhdpi-v4
baseFile 3 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
overlayFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
overlayFile 1 has flavor hdpi-v4
overlayFile 2 has flavor xhdpi-v4
overlayFile 3 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
found a match (0) for overlay file googleg_standard_color_18.png, for flavor mdpi-v4
found a match (1) for overlay file googleg_standard_color_18.png, for flavor hdpi-v4
found a match (2) for overlay file googleg_standard_color_18.png, for flavor xhdpi-v4
found a match (3) for overlay file googleg_standard_color_18.png, for flavor xxhdpi-v4
trying overlaySet Key=app_banner.png
trying overlaySet Key=app_icon.png
trying overlaySet Key=unity_static_splash.png
applyFileOverlay for layout
applyFileOverlay for anim
applyFileOverlay for animator
applyFileOverlay for interpolator
applyFileOverlay for transition
applyFileOverlay for xml
applyFileOverlay for raw
applyFileOverlay for color
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_tint.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_tint.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_tint.xml, for flavor 
applyFileOverlay for menu
applyFileOverlay for font
applyFileOverlay for mipmap
Processing image: res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
Processing image: res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon.png
Processing image: C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-11.0.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_full_open_on_phone.png
    (processed image C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-11.0.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_full_open_on_phone.png: 120% size of source)
    (processed image res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon.png: 90% size of source)
Processing image: C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-11.0.2\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_full_open_on_phone.png
Processing image: C:\Users\jimmy_000\Documents\Blaster\Temp\StagingArea\android-li<message truncated>
```

I'm getting this error when I tried to create an SDK and am scared that I will no longer be able to work on this after almost a year of work. What can I do to fix this? It stopped working when I added Google Admob to try and make some revenue from my game and now I can't upload any sdks. Help?

fggffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/760989/failed-to-re-package-resources-2.html

Comment: @user1767754 I'm sorry but that post was 2 years old and I don't have any of the files they were talking about for the problems with admob

Comment: @user1767754 is there anyway to just remove admob from my game? Would that help?